# Categorification of $Vec_G$

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, monoidal-categories, fusion-categories

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group.

We can think of the monoidal category $1Vec_G=Vec_G$ of $G$-graded $k$-vector spaces as a categorification of the group algebra $0Vec_G=kG$. How does this categorification pattern continue? Is there a nice recursive definition of the $n$-category $nVec_G$?

My guess is that we could use the equivalence $Vec_G\cong kG-mod$ in order to define $nVec_G$ as the $n$-category of module $(n-1)$-categories $(n-1)Vec_G-mod$. Is there a description in terms of the grading instead of modules?

Aha, I think its simply $nVec_G= \boxplus_{g \in G}\, nVec$, where $nVec$ is defined as above.

Comment: See here, for the next dimension up: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-vector+space

Comment: @Kevin Carlson Thx! In your reference are different definitions of 2-vector spaces. I suppose that in this setting, I should think of a (finite-dimensional) 2-vector space as a category equivalent to $Vec^{\boxplus n}$ for some n